# "unable to open file" when trying to use PPK key file converted from EC2 PEM key

Tags: putty, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Unable to connect to EC2 from Linux mint 20. Screen shots for the steps followed attached

[image: Ec 1]
[image: Ec 2]
[image: Ec 3]
[image: Ec 4]
[image: Ec 5]
[image: Ec 6]
[image: Ec 7]
[image: Ec 8]

In PuTTY I followed the steps

step 1 : to convert from .pek to .ppk I followed the link [pek-ppk](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/convert-pem-file-into-ppk/)

```
sudo puttygen my-keypair.pem -o my-keypair.ppk -O private
```

step 2 : For permission and user, I followed the [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connection-prereqs.html)

ubuntu user name : ubuntu and permissions ; chmod 400 my-keypair.pem.

[image: p1]
[image: p2]
[image: p3]
[image: p4]

Getting error:

[image: one]
[image: two]
[image: three]
[image: four]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running `puttygen` via `sudo`. So the converted key is stored as `root` with `root`-read-only access.

So your regular/desktop user cannot access it.

I do not think you need to run `puttygen` via `sudo`. Run it directly. That way the converted key will be stored under your user account.